# Is there a way to assign an array without doing a loop like this?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, initialization

I´ve just seen multidimensional arrays and as practice I first wanted to print out a string with this code; alas it didn´t work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
 char a[][20] = {"Hello"};
 printf("%s" , a [1]);
 getchar();
}
```

The only way I managed doing this was with a adding each character with a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
main()
{
char a[] = {"Hello"};
int i=0
while(a[i]!='\0')
 {
  printf("%c" , a[i]);
   i++;
  }
getchar();
}
```

What am I missing when initialising the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first fragment, you are accessing memory that's out of bounds.  The code that would work is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char a[][20] = {"Hello"};
    printf("%s\n", a[0]);
    getchar();
}
```

C arrays are indexed from zero.  You only defined and initialized `a[0]`; therefore, accessing `a[1]` is undefined behaviour.

In your second example, you could use `"%s"` OK:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{
    char a[] = {"Hello"};
    printf("%s\n", a);
    getchar();
}
```

Or you could use:

```
    printf("%s\n", &a[0]);
```

This is, of course, a single dimensional array.

Comment: Isn't `&a[0]` redundant? `&(&a[0])[0]` ?

Comment: Yes, `&a[0]` is redundant in this context.  If you had successive uses of `&a[0]`, `&a[3]`, `&a[6]`, and `&a[9]`, the symmetry of using `&a[0]` in lieu of `a` makes sense.  The compiler will almost certainly generate the same code regardless of which notation you use; it won't add 0 to the address.

Comment: Indeed it is a single dimensional array, I forgot to take in mind how arrays are indexed in C, thanks for the effort in showing me the correctly way though it is not neccesary in this example where I can leave it as you mentioned before since it is just one element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the pointer notation too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char a[][20] = {"Hello"};
    printf("%s\n", *( a + 0 ) );
    getchar();
}
```